# What do you call the reflection of a point through a line? Reflecting/reflection point?

Tags: phrase-request, mathematics

I want to write a sentence with math contents.

[image: Figure]

X, Y are points, and m is a line.
1. X is the reflecting point of Y with respect to m.
2. X is the reflection point of Y with respect to m.

Which sentence is more appropriate? 
Or is there any other good expression?

Comment: I doubt it's reflective. Is it capable of reflecting light or other radiation?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners Doyun! If you haven't already, please [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [check out the help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about domain-specific usages that are only relevant to advanced maths/geometry.

Comment: X and Y are axially symmetric. m is the axis of symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really say "reflected point" or "reflection point" instead, we would say one of these:

> M is the **line of symmetry** between X and Y.
>
> Y is the **reflection of** point X across line M.

Comment: @DoyunNam *Y* can also be called "the (mirror) image of point *X*". It would seem natural to me to say (but I can't find many Google results that support my intuition) that "*X* and *Y* are symmetric with respect to line *m*". There's another perspective from which you can observe this situation – note that line *m* perpendicularly divides line segment XY into two equal parts, making it a *perpendicular bisector of line segment XY*.